# Issues replacing dashes by <br> with javascript using wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, frontend

I am trying to replace all dashes(-) by a "br" but it gives me issues.

I have tried

```
var strNewString = $('.member__designation').html().replace(/-/g,'<br>');
$('.member__designation').html(strNewString);
```

Here is the html
[image]

Before applying the code above
[image]

After applying the code above
[image]

Comment: Please show the HTML  - it is never a good idea to replace stuff in HTML using regex

Comment: I included the html in my post now. Thank you for the remind :)

Comment: Please next time post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Pictures of code is not useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want

```
 $('.member__designation').each(function() {
   this.textContent = this.textContent.replace(/-/g,'<br>')
 })
```

assuming $('.member__designation') only has text and not html

IF there is only SIMPLE HTML like `<b>` then do

```
 $('.member__designation').each(function() {
   this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/-/g,'<br>')
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you grab all elements with class `.member__designation` and you replace them with whatever your regex grabs. I think you must change your implementation